# A .tex file that run on my HP laptop with Windows 10, but it does not run on my institute's Dell desktop with Windows 11

Tags: installing, miktex2.9

I have a .tex file that run on LaTex studio on my HP laptop (in which Windows 10 is installed); but it does not run on LaTex studio on my Dell desktop (in which Windows 11 is installed) and it shows an error titled `No room for a new \dimen'. Can somebody help me please, why is it not running on Dell desktop with Windows 11, how to resolve it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: compare the log-files of the two compilations.

Comment: unless your latex is older than 2015 it is virtually impossible to get that error, the number of available dimen was increased from 256 to over 32 thousand.